# Pentaho running slow when loading data into bigquery

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Simba driver for connecting pentaho to bigquery. connection is successfully test, but for ETL data from mySQL to Bigquery is running slow speed=0 (zero). The parameter list is already set in pentaho (createDisposition, location, Timeout, queryDialect , dryRun, Xverify, allowLargeResults, writeDisposition, datasetId, projectId. How do i solve this?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRXo2.png)